# Does the power of a power rule work on the double exponential function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

According to study.com, [https://study.com/learn/lesson/power-of-a-power-rules-examples.html#:~:text=The%20power%20of%20a%20power%20rule%20states%20that%20if%20a,the%20base%20remains%20the%20same](https://study.com/learn/lesson/power-of-a-power-rules-examples.html#:%7E:text=The%20power%20of%20a%20power%20rule%20states%20that%20if%20a,the%20base%20remains%20the%20same).
The power of a power rule states that if a base raised to a power is being raised to another power, the exponents are multiplied and the base remains the same. They give this example,

$(5^2)^4=5^8$

Wikipedia defines a double exponential function as a constant raised to the power of an exponential function. They say the general formula is $f(x)={a^b}^x=a^{(b^x)}$ which to me it seems to suggest that the power of a power rule does not work on the double exponential function but I am not sure about it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function

So is it true that the power of a power rule does not work on the double exponential function?

Comment: The symbol ${a^b}^x$ should not be used at all. It is ambiguous: it can be interpreted as ${a^{(b^x)}}$ or $({a^b})^x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Not true, there is a clear convention that power towers are calculated from above (from the right) if there are no paranthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that $(5^2)^4=5^{2\cdot 4}=5^{8}\not=5^{2^4}=5^{(2^4)}=5^{16}$ according your link on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. These two values are not the same even though someone without a good background in mathematics can confuse between the two. One needs to be very careful when dealing with exponential functions.

Comment: I will approve your answer for now.

Comment: Yes you're reason when we are working with power of power we need be careful with parentheses. You're welcome!